# How to Check the given string is a reserved keyword in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to check whether the given string is a reserved keyword in sql server.

I checked a lot in google ,but i didn't find one!!

for eg: If i am giving the input String as `'Order'`,sql statement should
        return whether it is reserved keyword.
        Is there any built-in stored procedures or function to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do that.

Here is the list of the known identifiers.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

I suggest to put these in an table and use it in a function / stored procedure.